# Change gradient in tikzpicture shade

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I will like to have made the red gradient start latter towards the center, (so the gradient is no longer linear but for example exponential instead) and have the gradient center pulled downwards instead of having it in the center.

[image]

I Hope that you can help

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);       

    \coordinate (A1) at (2.5,5);
    \coordinate (B1) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (A2) at (4 , 5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (4.5 ,1);
    \shade[inner color=red,outer color=white,fill opacity=0.8]  (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` file, you can set the vertical shading options with following code snippet.

```
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}%
```

Playing with `pgftransparent` and `color`values, I got the following output.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
 color(5bp)=(pgftransparent!10);
 color(60bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(70bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}%
\pgfdeclarefading{myfade}{%
  \pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);       

    \coordinate (A1) at (2.5,5);
    \coordinate (B1) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (A2) at (4 , 5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (4.5 ,1);
    \fill[red,path fading=myfade]  (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ADDENDUM: For both vertical and horizontal shading, one can use the `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` options together.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
 color(5bp)=(pgftransparent!10);
 color(60bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
 color(70bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}%
\pgfdeclarefading{myfadev}{%
  \pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
 color(5bp)=(pgftransparent!10);
 color(60bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
 color(90bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}%
\pgfdeclarefading{myfadeh}{%
  \pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@north}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);       

    \coordinate (A1) at (2.5,5);
    \coordinate (B1) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (A2) at (4 , 5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (4.5 ,1);
    \fill[red,path fading=myfadev]  (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);
    \fill[red,path fading=myfadeh]  (A2) to [bend right=10] (B2) to [] (B1) to [bend right=10] (A1) to (A2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I wanted :) THANKS

Comment: @JesperHagelskjær, your welcome.

Comment: Can you also create the gradient in the horizental direction so one have the gradient in both the vertical and horizental directions?

Comment: As stated in `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` file, change the `\pgfdeclareverticalshading` to `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading`.

Comment: @JesperHagelskjær, I've edited my answer to use both shadings.